# How do we know that the code is thread safe?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, intel-vtune

I am following [this tutorial](http://software.intel.com/en-us/node/471888) to understand how to remove locks , using VTUNE
This page says the following after collecting Vtune results:

**Identify the Hottest Code Lines**

> Click the  hotspot navigation button
>   to go to the code line that took the most Wait time. VTune Amplifier
>   highlights line 170 entering the critical section rgb_critical_section
>   in the draw_task function. The draw_task function was waiting for
>   almost 27 seconds while this code line was executing and most of the
>   time the processor was underutilized. During this time, the critical
>   section was contended 438 times.
>
> The rgb_critical section is the place where the application is
>   serializing. Each thread has to wait for the critical section to be
>   available before it can proceed. Only one thread can be in the
>   critical section at a time. You need to optimize the code to make it
>   more concurrent.

I was able to follow this tutorial until I reach the next section: [Remove the Lock](http://software.intel.com/en-us/node/471888)

**Remove the Lock**

> The rgb_critical_section was introduced to protect calculation from
>   multithreaded access. The brief analysis shows that the code is thread
>   safe and the critical section is not really needed.

My question is how do we know the code is thread safe?

As suggested I commented those line (EnterCritical... and LeaveCritical...), and saw huge performance gain, but I did not  get why this critical section is not required? Which analysis tells us this ?

The relevant code is here in analyze_locks.cpp:

```
public:
    void operator () (const tbb::blocked_range <int> &r) const {

        unsigned int serial = 1;
        unsigned int mboxsize = sizeof(unsigned int)*(max_objectid() + 20);
        unsigned int * local_mbox = (unsigned int *) alloca(mboxsize);
        memset(local_mbox,0,mboxsize);

        for (int y=r.begin(); y!=r.end(); ++y) {
            drawing_area drawing(startx, totaly-y, stopx-startx, 1);

            // Enter Critical Section to protect pixel calculation from multithreaded access (Needed?)
        //  EnterCriticalSection(&rgb_critical_section);

            for (int x = startx; x < stopx; x++) {
                color_t c = render_one_pixel (x, y, local_mbox, serial, startx, stopx, starty, stopy);
                drawing.put_pixel(c);
            }

            // Exit from the critical section
        //  LeaveCriticalSection(&rgb_critical_section);

            if(!video->next_frame()) tbb::task::self().cancel_group_execution();
        }
    }

    draw_task () {}

};
```

Comment: The question is whether any memory is accessed by more than one thread at a time.

Comment: One cannot reason "briefly" about thread safety. For example, this code was analysed step-by-step to eliminate data races when using OpenMP in here - http://www.viva64.com/en/b/0035/print/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is threadsafe if no global state (that is, state outside of this particular thread) is being modified. It's hard for us to tell what `render_one_pixel` and `drawing.put_pixel` actually does, and in what order it may need to be performed.

Assuming that the order of the calls to `put_pixel(c)` doesn't matter (or which thread makes the call), it would be safe to remove the critical section here. If there is strict ordering required, I'm not sure a critical section is the right solution anyway. (The same rules obviouysly apply to `render_one_pixel`, if it changes some global state,  which would of course also have to be taken into account in the "is it safe").